# Dynamic Form generation in JSF

Tags: forms, jsf, dynamic

I have to create an application in JSF. It has two forms for data entry in two sports events, but the requirement is that the user should be able to add other events i.e third, fourth and so on, with their own data entry attributes.

The respective data entry forms for these new events should be automatically generated (with all requisite tables in the BE DB), as well as business logic for save/edit functionality on the form.

Is this possible in JSF? if yes, how do I go about it?

Comment: This runtime update of the application is hardly possible with any framework (especially the db part). You should consider keeping the data in xml files or nosqldb that offers a schemaless design. Dynamic GUIs are possible with JSF since you could add components to the view tree using java code.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can create the components dynamically or have a `List<YourClass> lstYourClass`and use the `<ui:repeat>` tag component to show the user the contents of your `lstYourClass` in a generic way. IMO and based on your actual question, I would go with my second proposal.

Comment: You might get some inspiration from this: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:157882+[dynamic-forms]

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is possible in JSF 2. There are various ways to do this.

Programmatically adding components to the JSF component tree is supported, but there are a few caveats. The first is that you can't do this at a random time during request processing. Although the exact point is not (yet) specified, in practice the `PreRenderViewEvent` works perfectly for this.

Secondly, early versions of Mojarra 2.x contained several bugs that greatly restricted the amount and kind of programmatic changes to the component tree. MyFaces and later Mojarra versions are okay. If you're using Mojarra, you're probably safe if you use the latest released version at this time of writing.

A third caveat is that some components do not tolerate being added dynamically (the RichFaces DataTable used to be such component, perhaps it still is).

A basic example:

```
@ManagedBean
public class DynamicBacking implements SystemEventListener {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Faces.getViewRoot().subscribeToViewEvent(PreRenderViewEvent.class, this));
    }

    @Override
    public void processEvent(SystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        HtmlOutputText text = new HtmlOutputText();
        text.setValue("test");
        Faces.getViewRoot().getChildren().add(text);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isListenerForSource(Object source) {
        return source instanceof UIViewRoot;
    }
}
```

Another option is to use the DynaForm component that Oleg Varaksin created for PrimeFaces Extensions. See [Dynamic forms, JSF world was long waiting for](http://ovaraksin.blogspot.hu/2012/06/dynamic-forms-jsf-world-was-long.html).

Finally, as Luiggi mentions, depending on the complexity of your problem, perhaps a simple `<ui:repeat>` with components bound to e.g. a `Map` is all you need (but this depends on your exact requirements).

Answer (score 1):

I've done this kind of form inside my JSF CMS, I've created a custom JSF component that is linked to database so forms and fields are created and used after with the component. Basically I render a normal HTML form and intercept the POST content. I can send some source code if ever you are interrested.

Comment: Alexander Lavoie, I would like that code :) Can you send me on dario.bensic monky gmail com?

Comment: Well my solution is not AJAX, more a standard HTML print and servlet catch solution. Probably the other solution is more JSF friendly.

Comment: No problem if it is not AJAX. If you can send it, I would be very grateful!